# React Native : Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref.photo')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have to make a Camera app using `expo-camera`, and I went through this error saying that `_ref.photo is undefined`. I have no _ref.photo in my whole code, but I have a variable called `photo` in my context.

My context :

```js
type CameraShot = CameraCapturedPicture | undefined;

export type AccountContextType = {
  photo: CameraShot;
  setPhoto: (photo: CameraShot) => void;
};

export const AccountContext = React.createContext<
  AccountContextType | undefined
>(undefined);

const AccountProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = React.useState<CameraShot>(undefined);

  return (
    <AccountContext.Provider
      value={{
        photo,
        setPhoto
      }}
    >
      { children }
    </AccountContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AccountProvider;
```

My Camera function:

```js
  const { photo, setPhoto } = useContext(AccountContext) as AccountContextType;
  let _camera = useRef<Camera | null>();
  const [isBackCam, setIfBackCam] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(undefined as unknown);
  const [isCamReady, setIfCamReady] = useState(false);
  const [isPreviewModalShown, setIfPreviewModalShown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    Camera.getCameraPermissionsAsync()
    .then((response) => setStatus(response.status));
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {status === 'granted' ? (
        <>
          <Camera
            ratio="1:1"
            ref={e => _camera.current = e}
            onCameraReady={() => setIfCamReady(true)}
            type={isBackCam ? Camera.Constants.Type.back : Camera.Constants.Type.front}
            style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%' }}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
              <Text
                onPress={() => setIfBackCam(e => !e)}
                style={styles.shootText}
              > Flip </Text>
              <Text
                onPress={() => {
                  if (_camera && isCamReady) {
                    _camera.current?.takePictureAsync()
                    .then((response) => setPhoto(response))
                    return setIfPreviewModalShown(true);
                  }
                }}
                style={styles.shootText}> Shoot </Text>
            </View>
          </Camera>
          <Modal isVisible={isPreviewModalShown}>
            {photo !== undefined && (
              <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: photo.uri }}
                  height={photo.height}
                  width={photo.width}
                />
              </View>
            )}
          </Modal>
        </>
      ) : (
        <View style={{ margin: 15 }}>
          <Title extraLarge title='Accès refusé' />
          <Text style={{ marginTop: '70%', alignSelf: 'center' }}> Veuillez accorder l'accès à l'appareil photo </Text>
          <Spacer vertical />
          <Button
            innerText="Accorder l'accès"
            onPress={() => {
              Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
              .then((response) => setStatus(response.status));
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
```

I think that's a Context problem, but I didn't manage to put the light on it. Could you guys help me please ? What is undefined and how could I solve the problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: shouldn't `AccountContextType["photo"]` also be nullable? since you initialize the provider with null?

Comment: Yes, you're right ! But unfortunately it didn't solve my problem ...